# How does one use quasiquotes to obtain the type of a value?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes, scalameta

I’m trying to write the following:

```scala
val value: Int = 3
val tpe = typeOf(value)    // This is pseudocode. What should
                           // actually go on this line?
q"""
type U = $tpe
val v: U = $value
"""
```

Essentially, I need to capture the type of `value` (`Int`) in `tpe` and assign it to `U`. How does one do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
def getType[A: TypeTag](a: A): Type = typeOf[A]

val value: Int = 3
val tpe = getType(value) // Int
```

Connected question: [How does one obtain the type of the value that an AST represents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801743/how-does-one-obtain-the-type-of-the-value-that-an-ast-represents/)

Comment: Both of these solutions work — thank you. I’ve marked this as answered. I realized this morning, though, that I’ve asked a different question than the one I intended. In my question, `value` should be a `Tree`, not a value in itself. The correct question is here; if you could answer again there, I’d be most appreciative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801743/how-does-one-obtain-the-type-that-an-ast-represents

Comment: @DanielLi I edited my answer. I transfered other part of my answer there.