# How to get the runtime value of parameter passed to a Scala macro?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-reflect, scala-quasiquotes

I have an ostensibly simple macro problem that I’ve been banging my head against for a few hours, with no luck. Perhaps someone with more experience can help.

I have the following macro:

```scala
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

object MacroObject {
  def run(s: String): Unit =
    macro runImpl

  def runImpl(c: Context)(s: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    println(s)    // <-- I need the macro to know the value of s at compile time
    q"()"
  }
}
```

**The problem is this:** I’d like the macro to know the value `s` that is passed to it — not an AST of `s`, but the value of `s` itself.  Specifically, I’d like it to have this behavior:

```scala
def runTheMacro(str: String): Unit = MacroObject.run(str)

final val HardCodedString1 = "Hello, world!"
runTheMacro(HardCodedString1)    // the macro should print "Hello, world!"
                                 // to the console during macro expansion

final val HardCodedString2 = "So long!"
runTheMacro(HardCodedString2)    // the macro should print "So long!"
                                 // to the console during macro expansion
```

It is **guaranteed** that the only strings that will be passed to `runTheMacro` are hard-coded constant values (i.e., known at compile-time).

Is this possible, and how does one do this?

--

Edit: There are also the following constraints:

1. It must be a blackbox macro.
2. The macro signature must use `c.Tree`s, not `c.Expr[_]`s (legacy code; can’t change that part)
3. I do have a `toolbox` within the macro at my disposal if needed:

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
private val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()

/** Evaluate the given code fragment at compile time. */
private def eval[A](code: String): A = {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => u}
  val uTree: u.Tree = toolbox.parse(code)
  toolbox.eval(uTree).asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andriy. I’ve updated my question to clarify the constraints.

Comment: Andriy — I tried that trick in the link you sent, and unfortunately it generates an exception during macro expansion: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find proxy for str: String in List(value str, method run, object cmd2, package $sess, package ammonite, package <root>) (currentOwner= method wrapper )`

Comment: I think you should be able to pattern-match the `s` to be `Literal(Constant(s: String))`, and if it doesn't match, just call `c.abort`

Answer (score 1):

Your `eval` is runtime reflection's `eval`, compile-time macro's `eval` would be `c.eval`.

`"Hello, world!"` in

```
final val HardCodedString1 = "Hello, world!"
runTheMacro(HardCodedString1)
```

is a runtime value of `HardCodedString1`.

You can't have access to runtime value at compile time.

At compile time the tree of string `HardCodedString1` just doesn't know anything about right hand side of the `val` tree.

[Scala: what can code in Context.eval reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935330/scala-what-can-code-in-context-eval-reference/)

If you really need to use a runtime value inside the tree of your program you have to postpone its compilation till runtime

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

object MacroObject {
  val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()

  def run(s: String): Unit = {
    toolbox.eval(q"""
      println($s)
      ()
    """)
  }
}

runTheMacro(HardCodedString1)//Hello, world!
runTheMacro(HardCodedString2)//So long!
```

Alternatively at compile time you can somehow find the tree of enclosing class and look inside it for the `val` tree and take its right hand side

```
def runImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(s: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._

  var rhs: Tree = null

  val traverser = new Traverser {
    override def traverse(tree: Tree): Unit = {
      tree match {
        case q"$mods val $tname: $tpt = $expr" if tname == TermName("HardCodedString1") =>
          rhs = expr
        case _ => ()
      }
      super.traverse(tree)
    }
  }

  traverser.traverse(c.enclosingClass) // deprecated

  val rhsStr =
    if (rhs != null) c.eval[String](c.Expr(c.untypecheck(rhs.duplicate)))
    else c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "no val HardCodedString1 defined")

  println(rhsStr)

  q"()"
}

runTheMacro(HardCodedString1)//Warning:scalac: Hello, world!
```

Or for all such variables

```
def runImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(s: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._

  val sEvaluated =
    try {
      c.eval[String](c.Expr(c.untypecheck(s.duplicate)))
    } catch {
      case e: IllegalArgumentException if e.getMessage.startsWith("Could not find proxy") =>
        s match {
          case q"$sName" =>
            var rhs: Tree = null

            val traverser = new Traverser {
              override def traverse(tree: Tree): Unit = {
                tree match {
                  case q"$mods val $tname: $tpt = $expr" if tname == sName =>
                    rhs = expr
                  case _ => ()
                }
                super.traverse(tree)
              }
            }

            traverser.traverse(c.enclosingClass)

            if (rhs != null) c.eval[String](c.Expr(c.untypecheck(rhs.duplicate)))
            else c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"no val $sName defined")

          case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"unsupported tree $s")
        }

    }

  println(sEvaluated)

  q"()"
}

MacroObject.run(HardCodedString1) //Warning:scalac: Hello, world!
MacroObject.run(HardCodedString2) //Warning:scalac: So long!
```

`runTheMacro` will not work in this case: `Error: no val str defined`.
To make it work you can make it a macro too

```
def runTheMacro(str: String): Unit = macro runTheMacroImpl

def runTheMacroImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(str: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  q"MacroObject.run($str)"
}

runTheMacro(HardCodedString1) //Warning:scalac: Hello, world!
runTheMacro(HardCodedString2) //Warning:scalac: So long!
```